# The import com.eta cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse

What do I have to do to resolve this?

```
import com.eta.db.connection.HibernateSession;
import com.eta.db.connection.Save;
```

these are my imports in Eclipse. I work on Windows

Comment: you have to place the class files into your classpath, eighter download the jar or add the depenency to maven or whatever you use

Comment: I am not very familiar. How can I do that?

Comment: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_an_extra_library_to_my_project%27s_classpath%3F

Comment: I know how to add the jar, but I don't know exactly what jar. Can u give me a link or something?

Comment: eta.com is some proprietary software, you have to get the jar from them